# usage: curl [file] [URL] error while running curl commands

Tags: curl, libcurl

**curl/libcurl version** : 7.47.0

**curl -V** :
No download URL found!
File name: -V

**which curl** : /usr/local/bin/curl

**operating system** : Ubuntu 16.04.2 [LTS]

**command**: curl http://www.google.com
**output**:

```
No download URL found!
File name: http://www.google.com
```

**command**: curl
**output**:

`usage: curl [file] [URL]
             [file] [HTTP] fetches a file from an 'http' URL
             [file] [HTTPS] fetches a file from an 'https' URL
             [file] [FTP] fetches a file from a 'ftp' URL`

Answer (score 0):

It's a different curl...
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/curl/2016.2.1

Remove curl from `/usr/bin/` and `/usr/local/bin/`
Download and install it from https://curl.haxx.se/download.html